# git hook doesn't work with kie drools workbench

Tags: git, drools, githooks, kie

I am trying to sync a gitlab repository with the local git repository of my kie workbench project. 
I have created a project @ github to test automatic syncing with a post-commit hook and managed to get it to work when committing changes of a local repo but when I try the same with my workbench git repo it doesn't sync changes.
The steps I followed were:

1. I created a new repository and project in workbench
2. I set the origin url for my gitlab repository in `C:\jboss-eap-7.0\bin\.niogit\project.git` using `git remote set-url origin https://username:password@gitlab_URL/project_owner/project.git`
3. I added the post-commit file from my other project (the one I have tested on github)
4. Added a rule in order to have something in the project change and saved changed in order to commit (so that the post commit would execute)

Nothing happened. post-commit has the following lines:

```
#!/bin/sh

exec git push -u origin master
```

Do you have any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `chmod +x post-commit`